# How to integrate/display facebook videos to flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this code below, I like to display the videos from facebook to flutter app.
    But instead it only display a link to the video, when I click the link it brings me to facebook video. I like to display only the video and not the link, please help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html_view/flutter_html_view.dart';
//import 'package:html2md/html2md.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String html = '<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookAU/videos/10152167660372415/" data-width="500" data-show-text="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookAU/videos/10152167660372415/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookAU/videos/10152167660372415/">Happy New You</a><p>Here’s to a healthier, dancier, artier, funner New You in 2014.</p>Posted by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookAU/">Facebook</a> on Wednesday, January 8, 2014</blockquote></div>';

    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Center(
            child: new HtmlView(data: html),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Displaying Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuV8g.png)
[Video is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztuX4.png)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this version 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html

build HTML content like below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String html = '''
           <iframe width="200" height='200'
            src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/video.php? 
            allowfullscreen=false&autoplay=true&href=${FB_VIDEO_URL}" </iframe>
     ''';

    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: HtmlWidget(
            html,
            webView: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

replace FB_VIDEO_URL by your link 
it worked for me 
both facebook and youtube (youtube: repace attribute src in  tag) video. 
hope this helps.

Comment: Is there anyway we could play and pause video programatically ?